# How can convert date format in oracle

Tags: oracle

Convert date with 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' format:

eg: select TO_DATE(sysdate,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') From Dual;

Getting  error: ORA-01821: date format not recognized 01821. 00000 - "date format not recognized"

Comment: i think it's revelant json why mark down someone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Using Counter Function Resolved My Problem.
```

```js
      var i = 1;
        function count() {
            return i++;
        }
<script id="tableTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <tr><td>  ${count()} </td></tr>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `T` causes the Oracle error. It needs to be escaped by double quotes:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
2021-06-07T10:17:32
```